# Is a responsive design for less than 320px required?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have rebuilt my site to be responsive and it works great down to 320px. But the alignment differs at below 320px.

Do mobiles exist with less than 320px and is worth making the design fully responsive at below 320px?

Comment: You can do something like boostrap and that is `< 480px`

Comment: there are still some old android phones with a max-width of 240px but they get outdated more and more every day. for example: HTC Wildfire

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I always draw the line at 280px.
Think of this, the day will come where ppl will design responsive sites for devices like the apple watch, and it's a good practicing tool.
And why not be one of the first people who have at least tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not there are some devices < 320px width. Please see the following link: http://viewportsizes.com/

An example is some versions of the Blackberry Curve. Depends on what you want to accommodate. I don't tend to worry about anything below that, but some may well do.